# Google App Script - How to change Value of cell from a Range?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm self learner in app script and please don't judge me hard. I'm working on a project where I want to change cell value from a specific range, that are codes, to a numbers.

Here's what I have tried to write

```
function ShiftChange() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Roster");
  var range = ws.getRange("G5:NH17");
  var data = range.getValues();
  
  for(var i=1;i<ws.getLastRow();i++){
    for(var y=1;y<ws.getLastColumn();y++)
      var value = ws.getRange(i, y).getValue();
    if(value == 'E')
    var cell = ws.getCell(i,y);
    cell.setValue("08 - 17");
  }
}
```

I have this part
[image]

and I want this result

[image]

Here is the spreadsheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i3qMZgls3_WRPY5QSlQJo802D7xYDO80dih8E2-Vrd4/edit?usp=sharing

Can somebody help me with that?

Comment: I don't see a correlation between the `off` inside the input and output data...?

Comment: What's wrong with the code. **Describe the problem** as written in [mcve].

Comment: That is what I want to get back, If the cell have "Off***" to change it on "Off", if is "E***" change it to "08 - 17", and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then i think [this sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17oC_x_pyjXEUpH2Cm43028vkRzjGvTyJBJ-UeHJ_R7Q/edit?usp=sharing) is what you are after. There is a custom function inside Extension -> Apps script. You can use this function like a normal formula:

```
=MAPPING(A2:C10)
```

**The script:**

```
/**
* Returns mapping of roster
*
* @param {A1:A5} range Input range.
* @return {array} codes converted to numbers.
* @customfunction
*/
function MAPPING(input) {
  const mapping = {
    'E': '08 - 17',
    'D': '09 - 18',
    'M': '11 - 20',
    'L': '15 - 20',
    'N': '17 - 02',
    'O': 'Off'
  }
  const results = []

  input.forEach(row => {
    const tempArray = [];
    row.forEach(col => {
      const char = col.substring(0, 1)
      const number = mapping[char]
      tempArray.push(number)
    })
    results.push(tempArray)
  })

  return results
}
```

Comment: This is working perfectly, but in this way I need to add one more tab for the Mapping, and copy paste the data in other tab let say if I would like to change something like sick day, holiday etc. There is no way to do it with the script straight away?

Comment: No, just like every other formula: it is calculated.. just like an IF or SUM. You could change the script and paste as values in a different sheet and run it via a custom menu/button. But if you rerun the script you overwrite the values you changed.. both options needs adjustment at source level.